# Python-Parallel writing to file

Tags: python, json, file

I need to append text(lines) to .json file from number of servers parallel. This works but has some faults (writing line to center of other line). Does anybody know what to do with it? thanks

```
with open(sys.argv[2],'a') as w:

    w.writelines(json.dumps(record)+"\n")
```

Comment: can you use a lock on the file?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1. Lock the file somehow. This is system and filesystem dependent and I'm not sure how to do it in Python, but I'm sure it's possible.
2. Use some other synchronization mechanism. If all processes run on the same machine, you can probably use some OS mutex object. If they run on different machines, you might need some kind of lock server.
3. (Simplest) Have each process write to its own file, and have a single process that merges all the files.